# python - How to get armature from bone?

Tags: python, armature, add-on

In my python addon, I'm able to get the user's selected posebone and for reasons I need the armature it belongs to. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Python console.**

Bit of "educated guesswork" going on very little from question. I'll try and cover all bases here

Using python console, `C = bpy.context`

The armature object has context, in pose mode

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Armature']

>>> C.mode
'POSE'
```

The active pose bone

```
>>> pb = C.active_pose_bone
>>> pb
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["Bone"]
```

The pose bone belongs to the armature object which has context. Alternatively the `id_data` pointer tells us which ID object to which an object belongs.

```
>>> pb.id_data
bpy.data.objects['Armature']
```

The armature associated with this object.

```
>>> pb.id_data.data
bpy.data.armatures['Armature']
```

It would be really handy if in future you posted some pertinent code.

Comment: so ? how do you get the bone armature ? do you have parse all armatures ?